# Python kivymd TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have spent a fair amount of time trying to fix this,
my actual goal is to run a forloop to generate a list in kivymd and while doing so I got this error?

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

this is the code that I have simplified

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import *

KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: list
'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):

        ib = IconLeftWidget(icon='github')
        ibn = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(
            IconLeftWidget(icon='github')
            )
        
        self.root.ids.list.add_widget(ib)

MainApp().run()
```

need a generate a list via a forloop and use the icon as a button

`OneLineAvatarIconListItem( IconLeftWidget(icon='github') )`# error line
I know that the problem is that you can only pass one argument for the function but there got a be a way right!
please help T-T

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see any `for`-loop in code.

Comment: you should check documentation or source code to see how to use it - because it may need `names` argumens like `OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text='Hello')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done in one line but this works for me

```
    #ibn = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text='Hello')
    ibn = OneLineAvatarIconListItem()

    ibn.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon='plus'))
    ibn.add_widget(IconRightWidget(icon='minus'))

    self.root.ids.list.add_widget(ibn)
```

You could create own widget to make it simpler

```
class MyItem(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon='plus'))
        self.add_widget(IconRightWidget(icon='minus'))
 

# ... code ...


        #my_item = MyItem(text='World')
        my_item = MyItem()
        
        self.root.ids.list.add_widget(my_item)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import *

KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: list
'''

class MyItem(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon='plus'))
        self.add_widget(IconRightWidget(icon='minus'))
        
class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):

        ib = IconLeftWidget(icon='github')

        self.root.ids.list.add_widget(ib)

        ibn = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Hello", bg_color="lime")
        ibn.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon='plus'))
        ibn.add_widget(IconRightWidget(icon='minus'))
        
        self.root.ids.list.add_widget(ibn)

        my_item = MyItem(text="World", bg_color="red")
        
        self.root.ids.list.add_widget(my_item)
        
MainApp().run()
```

[image]